# *ngFor not working (angular 4)

Tags: node.js, angular

I've imported the required modules also checked for errors but nothing helps.
I am new to angular and still learning.

Here's is my app.module.ts file

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';


    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ContactsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

And here's the part of the code which is not working, but not working throwing any error either.

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor = "let contact of contacts" >
        <div class = "col-md-3">
          {{contact.first_name}}
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3">
            {{contact.last_name}}
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3">
              {{contact.phone}}
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3">
                <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value ="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** I've included my contact.srevice.ts file.

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { } 
  //retrieving contact_service

    getContacts() :Observable<any[]>
    {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
      .map(res => res.json());
    }

    //add contact method
    addContact(newContact){
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
      .map(res=>res.json());
    }

    //delete Contact Method
    deleteContact(id){
      return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact/'+id)
      .map(res=>res.json());
    }
}
```

[Network Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvzL5.png)

Comment: Also post your component code for more details

Comment: Here's the app.component.ts file import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'New App';
}

Comment: What's the error in your console?

Comment: Not throwing any error, but not getting the expected output, in fact not getting anything.

Comment: where you are initializing `contacts ` in you component code...

Comment: hi, updated my answer you need to add `subscribe` method at the end ..check my answer

Comment: You should post the component of this template, and not the module.

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1):

As per your `.ts` code you need to bind some data with your object named as `contacts` like this to get it work

```
contacts = [
    {first_name: "Pardeep", last_name: "Jain", phone: '90'},
    {first_name: "Pardeep", last_name: "Jain", phone: '90'},
    {first_name: "Pardeep", last_name: "Jain", phone: '90'}
  ]
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhjdqy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

## Update

You need to bind data whatever you get from this service like this -

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getContacts()
       .subscribe(data=> this.contacts = data)
    }
```

Comment: That is there in my mongo db and I am fetching it with getContacts method written in my contact.service.ts file getContacts()
    {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
      .map(res => res.json());
    }

Comment: Please Update your question with full code which you are using

Comment: i suggest you update you answer based on comment and updated question also

Comment: @PranayRana Thanks, Update answer as per question

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import {Contact} from './contact';

 @Component({ 
selector: 'app-root', 
templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) 
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit
{ 
     title = 'New App';
     contacts: Contact[];

     ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getContacts()
       .subscribe(data=> this.contacts = data)
    }
}
```

contact.service.ts file

```
    //make use of newer api of http 
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

 export class ContactService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 
    getContacts()  :Observable<Contact[]>
    { 
      return 
       this.http.get<Contact[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts');
    }



addContact(newContact) {
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
 };

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, httpOptions)
    .map(res=>res.json());
}
 }
```

Comment: I've implemented this part in my contacts.component.ts and contact.service.ts I am getting the required result when I call using get method on Postman or directly from url i.e., http://localhost:3000/api/contacts but not able to interpolate it on my html page.

Comment: Included :Observable<any []> with the method and imported {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; still not working, sir.

Comment: Sir, I've updated the question which now includes contact.service.ts file and I am not getting any error on my console and here's the result I am getting by http://localhost:3000/api/contacts [{"_id":"5ae801ab74a34218fcc095cf","first_name":"Prateek","last_name":"Astbana","phone":"7508506056","__v":0},{"_id":"5ae801d374a34218fcc095d0","first_name":"Prateek","last_name":"Asthana","phone":"7895632912","__v":0},{"_id":"5ae85a699c814c4a772ee591","first_name":"Pee","last_name":"Kay","phone":"9592026224","__v":0}

Comment: Still not getting any output, the worst part is I am not getting any error on the console. Anyways, thank you for your effort and time.

Comment: Yes, please see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/12PneqA6LnQgqsJumflDBErFPPOfKgY6n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated in the question. Can you see it now?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @PK - you need to add header ,     `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache', ` seems like and i hope you used httpclient

Comment: AppComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ContactService -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ContactService -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)

Comment: @PK - add this module : import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; and add import given in answer in you component